# Error: creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, javabeans

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' setting: 'true'

Answer (score 0):

it solved by adding
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
in application properties file.
here i used true instead of update so it was giving error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).